# Populate dropdownlist in mvc using JQuery onChange

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have two dropdown lists created in MVC. I want to repopulate the second dropdown list when a user selects something in the first dropdown list.

On page load I am populating the second dropdown list like this:

```
// Finds selected value
var selectedItem = departureRouteSelectList.First().Value.Substring(2, 2);

// Create new selectList for returnRoute
var returnRouteSelectList = Model.RoutesListConversely
        .Where(x => x.Value.StartsWith(selectedItem))
        .Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.Text, Value = x.Value });
```

The first line finds the last two letters which I use to compare on the `Model.RoutesListConversely`. The second line creates the list `returnRouteSelectList` based on what it finds using the two letters.

Can this be done using an `onChange()` method in JavaScript? So when you select something, this method runs and repopulate the second dropdown list?

**Code:**

```
<p>
   @Html.Label("Departure route:")
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Departureroute, departureRouteSelectList, 
                         new { @class = "dropdownlist", @id = "departureroute" })
</p>

 <p>
   @Html.Label("Return route:")
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Returnroute, returnRouteSelectList,
                         new { @class = "dropdownlist", @id = "returnroute" })
 </p>
```

**UPDATE:**

Have tried solve this using this code.. .but the problem is that it does not append data, but the clear function is working.

```
 // Getting value from departure dropdown
$("#departureroute").change(function () {

}).change(populateList);

function populateList() {

    // Clear dropdown for return route
    $("#returnroute").empty();

    // Gets last two letters.
    var word = (this.value).substring(2);

    // Gets the value from the departure route
    var selectedId = $("#departureroute").selectedItem.value;

    var returnlist = $("#returnroute");

    $("#departureroute").each()
    {
        if (word == selectedId.substring(2)) {
            returnlist.append("#departureroute")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve my problem using jquery each() function and append.

The following code did the trick:

```
 // On change departure route dropdown list
$("#departureroute").change(function () {

}).change(populateReturnlist);

function populateReturnlist() {

    // Clear dropdown for return route
    $("#returnroute").empty();

    // Gets last two letters.
    var word = (this.value).substring(2);

    var returnlist = $("#returnroute");

    $("#departureroute option").each(function () {

        // Gets the value from the departure route
        var selectedId = this.value.substring(0, 2);

        // Checks so the right routes gets added to list
        if (selectedId === word) {
            returnlist.append("<option>" + this.text + "</option>")
        }           
    });
};
```